# JavaScript not functioning when uploaded to the server

Tags: javascript, file-upload

I am attempting to build a basic microsite and using JavaScript found here 
https://github.com/bgrins/TinyColor on my website.

Everything works fine when I am working locally, however the script doesn't work when I upload it.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Are there any errors being returned from the console to help debug the issue?

Comment: I think this may be off-topic because it is about web administration and as such better fits to http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @AnthonyForloney Nope. Everything is fine. Feel free to pull the code from the my site.

Comment: @Fritz By accessing your website, I am receiving an `403` error for `tinycolor.js`. Without knowing the configuration of your webserver, it seems that this may be a setup issue.

Comment: @AnthonyForloney so you think its an issue on the hosting side?

Comment: @AnthonyForloney thanks for the help! the issue was permissioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FILE permissions required

Needs file permissions for tinycolor.js. go to hosting server and provide full permissions

try 1: provide read permissions for tinycolor.js and upload it to your server
try 2: give full permissions to one folder and place your file in that folder on server and change the url in html page

Comment: if you have hosted on iis server then you need to give 777 permissions for the folder